# How to modify a form property for more than one forms in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I want to know if I can modify a form property one time and have it apply to all forms (design-time).

I have 25 forms in my c# project. I need to change their size, all to the same value. It takes a long time to change their size one by one. Thus, I am looking for a way to change the sizes one time and apply to all forms using Visual Studio.

Comment: What is wrong in using a for-loop and `control.Size=blabla`

Comment: While I believe the answer to be "No", it would help if you specified which version of Visual Studio

Comment: @EZI That doesn't work at design time

Comment: Yes, you can do a search and replace across the entire solution, but you would still have to check each form and possibly rearrange controls.

Comment: @EZI That is okay. But I design those forms for renew. And it should not be in run time.

Comment: Is it something you define in a common config file and pull this information in the class where you are defining and modifying the control?

Comment: To close voters, I don't see any of the reasons chosen applying here. Its very clear what he is asking, Visual Studio is a tool used by programmers, and there is no code involved here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET the visual studio version is professional 2013

Comment: @SilviaDoomra Yes actually it is a class that I pull some properties from that class. But it is not as this. I would like to change it like applying to all forms for design

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes there is no code. I am asking the way for changing the normal form size property in one time in visual studio like replace all option for codes

Comment: I see the need for this in design time, but you should still consider a coding solution to make sure the 25 forms stay the same size at run-time. Also, it tells another developer that this is a requirement. Otherwise, they'll need to figure it out on their own or read some documentation.

Comment: Yes, thanks @JeffO . I am managing it in coding for runtime. I asked the design part just for my team mates. To show the actual appearance of forms to friens in design time.

Answer (score 2):

For WinForms, what the VS designer actually does is just to write a piece of code that's run in the constructor (within `InitializeComponent`), and that code in turn is saved in the "formname.designer.cs" file.

Based on the comment by *Enigmativity*, all you need to do is to edit that file and replace the line of code that gives forms their sizes. This can be done with the "replace in files" function. Look for this line:

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(269, 77);
```

in all .designer.cs files (of course your actual size will be different, so be cautious with the search expression). Just replacing those numbers with the new size will do the trick. Make sure all forms' designers are closed so that they don't overwrite the changes.

Comment: If `Form.Localizable` set to `true`, then you need to search `.resx` files. Because value of `ClientSize` moved to resource files and retrieved from there while `InitializeComponent` method executing.